# List first element being set to null after backing up to firebase

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The first element of the list teams is being set to null after I back the list up to firebase. On firebase, it shows that the list has a first element, but afterwards, in my actual program, after backing up, it shows that the first element becomes null. This is the activity that manages it. The addTeam method is where I add the team and back up to firebase.

```
public class TournamentManager extends AppCompatActivity {

    Firebase ref;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    EditText teamNumber;
    Button cancel;
    Button addTeam;
    public static List teams;
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tournament_manager);
        Toolbar b = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra("Tournament Name");
        b.setTitle(extra);
        setSupportActionBar(b);
        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("Position", 0);
        ref = AdminMain.ref.child("" + position).child("teams");
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addTeamDialog();
                if (teams == null){
                    //hi
                }
            }
        });
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.teamList);
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                teams = (ArrayList) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (teams == null){
                    teams = new ArrayList();
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++) {
                        String temp = (String) (((HashMap) teams.get(i)).get("name"));
                        teams.set(i, new Team(temp));
                    }
                }
                setAdapter();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                //do nothing
            }
        });

    }

    public void setAdapter(){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(TournamentManager.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teams);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                teams = teams;
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addTeamDialog(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_team, null);
        final AlertDialog diag = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(v)
                .create();
        diag.show();
        teamNumber = (EditText) diag.findViewById (R.id.editText);
        addTeam = (Button) diag.findViewById(R.id.addTeam);
        addTeam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addTeam(teamNumber.getText().toString());
                diag.hide();
            }
        });
        cancel = (Button) diag.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                diag.hide();
            }
        });
    }

    public void addTeam(String s){
        teams.add(new Team(s));
        ref.setValue(teams);
        if (teams.get(0) == null){
            //hi
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of class `Team`.

Comment: When you add multiple teams, it is only the first that appears as null?

Comment: I'm actually unable to add more than 2 teams right now because the app is crashing due to adapter, etc. errors. I'll try to debug these other problems before I can get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a problem with your class `Team`. Please post its definition.  Does it include an override for method `toString()` that returns the value of `name`?  The documentation for [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) states: "Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.".

Comment: I do override the toString method in my team class; it returns the team name. Thanks